# C# - method that accepts any type of parameter (reusing an existing method)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a method, `serializetoxml`, that accepts an object of type `obj1` as its parameter:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        obj1 myobj = new obj1();
        serializetoxml(myobj);    
    }
}

public class obj1
{
    public string a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }
    public bool c { get; set; }
}

public static void serializetoxml(obj1 myobj)
{
    XmlSerializer myserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(obj1));
    TextWriter mywriter = new StreamWriter("C:\\my.xml");
    myserializer.Serialize(mywriter, myobj);
    mywriter.Close();
}
```

Now I have a class, `obj2`, that I want to pass as its parameter

```
public class obj2
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public bool b { get; set; }
    public List<string> c { get; set; }
}
```

How do I reuse the `serializetoxml` method to be able to accept another type of parameter, so that I will not write the same method again and change the typeof to `obj2`?

```
obj2 myobj = new obj2();
serializetoxml(myobj);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the following

```
public static void serializetoxml(object myobj) {
    XmlSerializer myserializer = new XmlSerializer(myobj.GetType());
    TextWriter mywriter = new StreamWriter("C:\\my.xml");
    myserializer.Serialize(mywriter, myobj);
    mywriter.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Add a type parameter:

```
public static void serializetoxml<T>(T myobj)
{
    XmlSerializer myserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    TextWriter mywriter = new StreamWriter("C:\\my.xml");
    myserializer.Serialize(mywriter, myobj);
    mywriter.Close();
}
```

You would then use it like:

```
serializetoxml<obj2>(myobj);
```

or

```
serializetoxml<obj1>(myobj);
```

With the magic of type parameter inference, you can omit the type parameter entirely (but it's OK if you want to leave it there):

```
serializetoxml(myobj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the method to a static class, and make it an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), like this:

```
internal static class Extensions {
    public static void SerializeToXml<T>(this T myobj)
        {
            XmlSerializer myserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            TextWriter mywriter = new StreamWriter("C:\\my.xml");
            myserializer.Serialize(mywriter, myobj);
            mywriter.Close();
        }
}
```

You can now use it as if it were an instance method. You need to put your `Extensions` class into the same namespace, or add a `using` directive for it.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

- generics: `Serialize<T>(T obj)` and `typeof(T)`
- object: `Serialize(object obj)` and `obj.GetType()`

I actually prefer the second for serialization, based on bitter bitter experience, but both are valid.

Comment: Wow, seems very useful. But to someone that is new to C#, means nothing at all. I've been out of the programming loop for a few years now. But from a C Lang and some Java and even PHP. But all seems dead so I gave it up. But I'm programming C# now because the God's of Evil Apple and decided to banish Adobe Flash and thus AS3 is gone...

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void serializetoxml(object myobj)
{
    XmlSerializer myserializer = new XmlSerializer(obj1.GetType());
    TextWriter mywriter = new StreamWriter("C:\\my.xml");
    myserializer.Serialize(mywriter, myobj);
    mywriter.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's really no problem. Just make your serialization method work on a generic type.
See Stack Overflow question *[Using generics with XmlSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670138/using-generics-with-xmlserializer)*.